# Unable to access other Volume in Vaio E series

Tags: mount

Error mounting `/dev/sda6` at `/media/ravi/New Volume`:

```
mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda6" "/media/ravi/New Volume"
```

Exited with:

```
non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda6': Operation not permitted

The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Comment: The answer is in the question.  Boot Windows, and do a complete shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the Windows hibernation function. You should see the question [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation).

And to turn the hibernation function off, the video [Turning hibernation off in windows 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZaZEIadu1U) can help you.